# How to manage java file with tablayout and fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I was developing a simple app with firestore. in this case, for better functionality and customer friendly, I input the tablayout concept with fragments to my app. when I using, some errors were coming up. I tried but I cannot fix it. So what I want to is, what is case which affect to that kind of error?? If you are familiar which I was saying, please help me.

```
this is the java file that i want to code in one fragment. 
package com.example.work_home;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static com.example.work_home.R.id.txt_select_leave;

public class Apply extends Fragment {
    private AutoCompleteTextView SelectLeave, LeaveType;
    TextInputEditText FromDate, ToDate;
    EditText Reason;
    private DatePickerDialog dataPickerDialog_from;
    private DatePickerDialog dataPickerDialog_to;
    Button BtnSubmit;
    BottomNavigationView BtnBottom;
    View v;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser FUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    public String UserId = FUser.getUid();

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apply, container, false);
        return v;
        SelectLeave = v.findViewById(txt_select_leave);
        LeaveType = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_leave_type);
        FromDate = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_from_user);
        ToDate = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_to_user);
        Reason = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_reason_user);
        BtnSubmit = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        BtnBottom = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_bottom_navigation_leave);


        BtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String selectLeave = SelectLeave.getText().toString();
                String leaveType = LeaveType.getText().toString();
                String fromDate = FromDate.getText().toString();
                String toDate = ToDate.getText().toString();
                String reason = Reason.getText().toString();

                DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("users").document(UserId);
                DocumentReference documentReference_two = documentReference.collection("ApplyLeave").document();

                Map<String, Object> LeaveData = new HashMap<>();
                LeaveData.put("u_select_leave", selectLeave);
                LeaveData.put("u_leave-type", leaveType);
                LeaveData.put("u_from_date", fromDate);
                LeaveData.put("u_to_date", toDate);
                LeaveData.put("u_reason", reason);

                documentReference_two.set(LeaveData);

            }
        });


        FromDate.setText(getTodayDate());
        ToDate.setText(getTodayDate());

        initDatePicker_from();
        initDatePicker_to();

        String[] Select_Leave = new String[]{
                "Casual Leave", "Sick Leave", "Annual Leave ", "Maternity Leave", "Paternity Leave"
                , "Compensatory Off", "Other"};

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                Apply.this, R.layout.dropdown_item, Select_Leave
        );
        SelectLeave.setAdapter(adapter);

        String[] Leave_Type = new String[]{
                "Full Day", "Half Day", "Other"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_one = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                Apply.this, R.layout.dropdown_item, Leave_Type
        );
        LeaveType.setAdapter(adapter_one);

        /*BtnBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.logout:
                        Intent logout = new Intent(Apply.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(logout);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        Intent home = new Intent(Apply_leave.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(home);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.user:
                        Intent user = new Intent(Apply_leave.this, UserProfile.class);
                        startActivity(user);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    /*case R.id.alerts:
                        Intent alerts = new Intent(Apply_leave.this, Notifications.class);
                        startActivity(alerts);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });*/


    }

    private String getTodayDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month = month + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return makeDataString(day, month, year);


    }


    private void initDatePicker_from() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dataSetListener_from = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                month = month + 1;
                String date_from = makeDataString(dayOfMonth, month, year);
                FromDate.setText(date_from);
            }
        };
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int style = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;
        dataPickerDialog_from = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dataSetListener_from, year, month, day);
        dataPickerDialog_from.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private void initDatePicker_to() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dataSetListener_to = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                month = month + 1;
                String date_to = makeDataString(dayOfMonth, month, year);
                ToDate.setText(date_to);
            }
        };
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int style = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT;
        dataPickerDialog_to = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dataSetListener_to, year, month, day);
        dataPickerDialog_to.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private String makeDataString(int dayOfMonth, int month, int year) {
        return getMonthFormat(month) + " " + dayOfMonth + " " + year;
    }

    private String getMonthFormat(int month) {
        if (month == 1)
            return "JAN";
        if (month == 2)
            return "FEB";
        if (month == 3)
            return "MAR";
        if (month == 4)
            return "APR";
        if (month == 5)
            return "MAY";
        if (month == 6)
            return "JUN";
        if (month == 7)
            return "JUL";
        if (month == 8)
            return "AUG";
        if (month == 9)
            return "SEP";
        if (month == 10)
            return "OCT";
        if (month == 11)
            return "NOV";
        if (month == 12)
            return "DEC";

        return "JAN";

    }

    public void openDatePicker_from(View view) {
        dataPickerDialog_from.show();

    }

    public void openDatePicker_to(View view) {
        dataPickerDialog_to.show();


    }
}
```

**************this is layout of my tablayout(main.xml) file*********[enter image description here][1]

******* this is the layout of apply.xml file********
[enter image description here][2]

*************this is my adapter file******************

```
package com.example.work_home;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VPAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();


    public VPAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentArrayList.size();
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        fragmentArrayList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitle.add(title);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return fragmentTitle.get(position);
    }
}

So if You are familiar with these kind of problem please help me..
```

*****************errors in the code****************

```
error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_one = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                           ^
error: incompatible types: Apply cannot be converted to Context
        dataPickerDialog_from = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dataSetListener_from, year, month, day);
                                                     ^
error: unreachable statement
        SelectLeave = v.findViewById(txt_select_leave);
        ^
******************errors****************************
[enter image description here][3] 
[enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDZcQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAVCB.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbChu.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuDg3.png
```

Comment: *"when I using, some errors were coming up. I tried but I cannot fix it."* - Please tell us **clearly** and **accurately** what those errors were.

Comment: what I want to do this stephen , just I want to add apply.java file to one of the fragment that i mentioned above.  can i put the images of my code?? the i can show you...

Comment: No.  We want you to provide the error messages, stacktraces, whatever AS TEXT ... not as screenshots or images.

Comment: I think java file not recognized by the android studio....

Comment: I  am really sorry, I am new comer for stackoverflow.... please can you help how I show the error message?? can i copy the error code and paste it or something...

Comment: Yes. You can copy-and-paste it into the Question.  Please do that.  Use the [EDIT button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68644474/edit) beneath the question tags ... and paste the information into the Question.

Comment: error: incompatible types: Apply cannot be converted to Context
        dataPickerDialog_from = new DatePickerDialog(this, style, dataSetListener_from, year, month, day); this is error one
                                                     ^

Comment: error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_one = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                           ^

Comment: now I added. please consider it!!

Comment: Do it properly.  Follow the clear instructions that I gave you.  Then (and only then) will I see if I can figure out what your problem is.  Seriously dude, you are trying my patience.  I shouldn't have to tell you something 5 times ...

Comment: please dont misunderstand me. sorry dude i'm trying to figure these things.... ok I got the error messages from logcat and paste it... can you??

Comment: So ... you know how to copy and paste into a comment.  And you know how to edit the question 'cos I told you how to do it!  (Use the "edit" button beneath the question tags.) So what you need to do is edit the question AND copy and paste into it.

Comment: I add it to question in the bottom part

Comment: please if you think I cannot understand the your idea, please giveup. sometimes i think I cannot present my probelm to you. sorry!

Comment: Phew!  You got there in the end.

Comment: Note: the above was not about me not understanding you.  It was all about you asking the question **properly** according to the Stack Overflow requirements.  (Hopefully ... you learned how to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Java compilation errors.

```
error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_one = new ArrayAdapter<>(
              Apply.this, R.layout.dropdown_item, Select_Leave
        );
```

So the problem is that all of the constructors for `ArrayAdapter` require a `Context` as the first argument.  But you have given it an `Apply`.  And  `Apply` has been declared as a `Fragment` ... and a `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

```
error: incompatible types: Apply cannot be converted to Context
        dataPickerDialog_from = new DatePickerDialog(
             this, style, dataSetListener_from, year, month, day);
```

This is pretty much the same problem.  The `DatePickerDialog` constructors all require a `Context` as the first argument, but `this` is an `Apply` which is not a `Context`.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you should be calling `getContext()` on your `Apply` / `Fragment` instance and passing the result to those two constructors ...

---

Note that you can (and should) **find and read** the javadocs for the Android library classes to understand how to use them.  For example, the javadocs for `Fragment` tell you that a `Fragment` is not a `Context` ... but it does have a `getContext()` method.

Comment: Ok can you tell me what it the place that getContext() apply in the code???

Comment: In the first one ... change `Apply.this` to `Apply.this.getContext()`.  And the second one you should be able to work out for yourself.

Comment: so these errors now fix. but error was set in the findviewbyid section. I was copy and paste the error. can I get the help??

Comment: This is the LAST help I am going to give you.  Any statement after a `return` is unreachable.  Look at the line before the one that gave that compilation error.  The fix is obvious.